# php code to output multiple data separated in comma

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project to store information, i need to save datas in my database using a multiple select option.
after saving to database it will store like this `Item1,item2,item3` separating with comers.
Now i need to echo it out from database so it will display like this

item1

item2

item3

i don't want it to display the way it is in my database `Item1,item2,item3`

**Here is more explanatory image**

Here is my multiple select image sample
[image]

Here is how i want to output to be like

[image]

Please i don't have any sample code because i don't know how to start writing this and am very new in php i also don't know what to search online but i know you can help me.

Comment: refer this http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Check how its storing the items. You can use inspect element to find out the value="?, ?, ?"

Comment: `$itemIds = explode(',',$stringWithIds);` Although I`d recommend to add another table to store them...

Comment: so it is like tagging?

Comment: @yahoo yes like taging

Comment: @KA_lin Let me try that you have said, i don't want to create new table for that

Comment: @Plum it store the datas like this `Item1,item2,item3`

Comment: @Micheal Don't you want to get objects having `item1` set? Or search by items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the string into a variable and use `explode()` function to make an array of items. Example:

```
$string = 'item1, item2, item3';

$arrayOfItems = explode(',', $string);

foreach($arrayOfItems as $item) {
   echo '<button>'.$item.'</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored like item1,item2,item3 in the database. Then show it as is to the value of the textbox. For ex:-

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $items; // item1,item2,item3 ?>">
```

Comment: Then after that what else will happen?

Comment: @Micheal  Try adding that to your code and see whether you getting the right result or not.

Answer (score -3):

$data="item1,item2,item3";    $dt=explode(",",$data);    for($i=0;$i< count($dt); $i++)   {  echo "".$dt[$i]."";   } ?>